# How to do ant style file filtering when copying files

Tags: cp

With Ant you can use a filter like:

```
**/target/*.war
```

That means all the paths that have target in them as the last directory.
This will match

- `a/b/target/X.war`
- `a/target/Y.war`
- `a/b/c/target/Z.war`

I would like to be able to copy in ubuntu with this kind of filtering...

Best case would to do

```
cp **/target/*.war DESTINATION
```

I know this doesn't work. Is there some way in ubuntu I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the bash shell, you can enable this behavior by setting the shell `globstar` option e.g.

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ cp -v **/target/*.war ../target
`a/b/c/target/Z.war' -> `../target/Z.war'
`a/b/target/X.war' -> `../target/X.war'
`a/target/Y.war' -> `../target/Y.war'
```

You can turn the option off again (unset) with `shopt -u globstar`. Type `help shopt` at the bash prompt for more information about shell options.

Comment: nifty... just a small question: does the option persist if the terminal is ended? I tested it, it doesn't

Comment: You can add it to the startup options in your ~/.bashrc file (in fact the default .bashrc has an entry for it which you can just uncomment i.e. remove the # in front of)